# Call for SKProductsRequest getting failed when I build using Xcode version higher than 11.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jenkins-pipeline, in-app-purchase

when I run my code using Xcode 11.2.1 all working as expected,
but when I try to create a build for the same code using updated Xcode version *(I tried Xcode 11.4.1/11.7.1/12.0)* SKProductsRequest call get failed & in `didFailWithError` I get *unknown error* as a message

FYI here is my sample code,

```
public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.completion?(SubscriptionPricing(products: response.products))
        }
    }
    
    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.completion?(SubscriptionPricing(products: []))
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than continuing to ask essentially same question, it would be better if you improved the question you already asked. What error code do you get?  What provisioning profile and signing certificates are you using? Are you sure they are consistent between your environments?

Comment: Sorry @Paulw11, I mistakenly add the new I want to edit this one.
Answer to your question All provisioning profile and signing certificates updated & working. As I investigate, It seems that my pipeline was using updated Xcode so I change my question for a better understanding of the issue